# How to access my angular $scope inside my custom callback?

Tags: angularjs, scope

My callback's below are not able to update/access my $scope variables (or, the changes aren't showing for some reason), how can I achieve this?
The callback's are being called, but I think something clearly isn't right with my javascript scoping here.

```
function ReportsCtrl($scope) {
    var self = this;
    $scope.analyticsIsReady = false;
    $scope.analyticsInitStatus = '';

    //$scope.originCompositionChart = new Chart__('originCompositionChart', reportsClient.getOriginCompositionData, true, false);
    $scope.originCompositionChart = new Chart__('originCompositionChart', null, true, false);
    $scope.charts = new Array($scope.originCompositionChart);

    $scope.showIncludedCharts = function () {
    };

    //todo not working
    this.updateAnalyticsInitStatus = function (status) {
        console.log('boom; ' + status);
        $scope.analyticsInitStatus = status;
    };

    //todo not working
    this.handleAnalyticsInitSuccess = function (status) {
        $scope.analyticsInitStatus = 'Initialisation complete';
        $scope.analyticsIsReady = true;
    };

    window.analyticsInitialiserClient = new AnalyticsInitialiserClient__(this.updateAnalyticsInitStatus, this.handleAnalyticsInitSuccess);

}
```

Comment: when using event callbacks that aren't part of angular scope need to use `$apply` when updating scope variables

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @charletfi suggested, you need to wrap callbacks from outside Angular in an `$apply` to instruct Angular to run a digest cycle to determine changes.

```
// Should now work
this.updateAnalyticsInitStatus = function (status) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        console.log('boom; ' + status);
        $scope.analyticsInitStatus = status;
    });
};
```